# Craftercms: How to access Crafter engine properties in groovy controllers?

Tags: java, groovy, content-management-system, crafter-cms

Is it possible to access the crafter engine properties (defined in server-config.properties) from groovy? As an example: access the property “crafter.engine.site.default.staticAssets.path” ...

So far I have tried accessing the "crafter.properties" bean using the applicationContext object, but I haven't been able to access the configured properties from that bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crafter Engine provides a Groovy variable called globalProperties that you can use to access properties defined in server-config.properties:

```
globalProperties.getProperty("crafter.engine.site.default.staticAssets.path")
```